# react material Ui textfield type password disable autofill from browser when focused on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using react material UI 4 and I want to disable the browser autofill/auto complete suggestion when I focus on my password field which is coming from TextField.

My requirement is to not show suggestions when we focus on that field and the field type is password. For username and email it is working but for some reason it is not working for password field.

[image]

I have tried below appraoch but nothing is working

```
<TextField
   inputProps={{
      autoComplete: 'off'
   }}
/>

===============================
<TextField
  inputProps={{
     ...params.inputProps,
     autoComplete: 'new-password',
   }}
 />

=====================
<TextField
 autoComplete="new-password"
/>

=========================
//Below works but then this field no more acts as a password field

<TextField
   label="Password"
   className={classes.textField}
   name="password"
   inputProps={{
      type:"password",
      autoComplete: 'new-password'
   }} />
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you tried <form autocomplete="off">?

Comment: I dont have form tag over my component

Comment: then will suggest to give it a chance

Comment: Not working brother

Answer (score 1):

try using the method I'm adding below.
It worked for me.

```js
<Textfield
  inputProps={{
    autocomplete: 'new-password',
    form: {
      autocomplete: 'off',
    },
  }}
  />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Updated Answer:
 `<TextField autoComplete="chrome-off" />`

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Not working bro

Comment: Are you still getting same issue ?? @tyler

Comment: When I click on my password field it start showing the saved password
if I convert that feild to text field my all the above solutions are working
I am using OutlinedInput field with input adornment to show and hide password

Answer (score 0):

```
const [readOnly, setReadOnly] = useState(true)

// render

<TextField
 label="Password"
 className={classes.textField}
 name="password"
 readOnly={readOnly}
 onFocus={e => setReadOnly(false)}
  sx={{
        '& input': {
                     textSecurity: 'disc',
                     '-moz-text-security': 'disc',
                     '-webkit-text-security': 'disc',
                    },
      }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time answering a question, so I apologize if my explanation is not the clearest. In my specific case, I have an autocomplete select where I use a textfield inside it. I encountered a similar issue, but in my case, it didn't make sense to have browser suggestions in a select element where you only need to select elements and, of course, write. After hours of searching i found this, it worked for me

```
renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} name='new-password' />}
```

i hope it works for anyone that is using this